# Batch Album Art embedding with FFmpeg

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg

I want to convert all Flacs in a folder to ALAC m4a and embed the Album Art

With this code it embeds the same jpg into every m4a, how can I instead extract the album art from each flac and  then have it embedded into the corresponding m4a?

```
@echo off
for %%G in (*.flac) do ffmpeg -i "%%G" -map 0:v -codec copy cover.jpg
for %%F in (*.flac) do ffmpeg -i "%%F" -vn -acodec alac "%%~nF.m4a"
(FOR /F "tokens=*" %%E IN ('dir /b *.m4a') DO atomicparsley "%%E" --artwork cover.jpg --overWrite)
(del cover.jpg)
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is replacing `cover.jpg` in second, fourth and fifth line as shown below:

```
@echo off
for %%G in (*.flac) do ffmpeg -i "%%G" -map 0:v -codec copy "%%~nG.jpg"
for %%F in (*.flac) do ffmpeg -i "%%F" -vn -acodec alac "%%~nF.m4a"
for /F "eol=| delims=*" %%E in ('dir /b *.m4a 2^>nul') do atomicparsley "%%E" --artwork "%%~nE.jpg" --overWrite
del /Q "*.jpg"
pause
```

But a better solution is using just one **FOR** loop instead of three **FOR** loops with three different loop variables.

```
@echo off
for %%I in (*.flac) do (
    ffmpeg.exe -i "%%I" -map 0:v -codec copy "%%~nI.jpg"
    if exist "%%~nI.jpg" ffmpeg.exe -i "%%I" -vn -acodec alac "%%~nI.m4a"
    if exist "%%~nI.ma4" atomicparsley.exe "%%I" --artwork "%%~nI.jpg" --overWrite
    if exist "%%~nI.jpg" del "%%~nI.jpg"
)
pause
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`

The documentations of [FFmpeg](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg/) and [AtomicParsley](http://atomicparsley.sourceforge.net/) should be also read by everyone using these two applications which was not done by me because I don't use them.

PS: It would be better to specify `ffmpeg.exe` and `atomicparsley.exe` with full qualified file name (drive + path + name + extension) enclosed in double quotes. Then Windows command processor `cmd.exe` would not need to search for these two executables using the environment variables `PATHEXT` and `PATH` in the loop before every execution.

Comment: Thanks for the post, both of your solutions appear to work once I transfer the files over to the device. For some reason when I play the m4a in VLC on Windows they still all have the same album art, but once on the device they have the right ones. Might be a Windows cache thing